# postgis calculate distance between point & polygon/circle

Tags: postgis, polygon, point, distance

By basic requirement is to find the nearby fences to a particular point(user `lat long alt`) within a N meters.

I have list of polygon/circle in DB with 900913 srid

`ST_Force_3D(st_geomfromtext('polygon((' || p_geometrytext  || '))', 900913))`

where `p_geometrytext` is a series of `long lat alt` with "," separator.

I have point like this `79.268309 17.057432 0.0`
I tried below code

```
select ST_Distance(
     ST_SetSRID((select "Fence" from "GeoFence" where "FenceId"=13), 4326),
     ST_GeomFromText('POINT(79.268309 17.057432 0.0)', 4326), 
     true)
```

I used 4326 as srid, because 900913 is giving error.

I went throw this [doc](http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/measurement.html#distance) but unable to use it properly. I am new to postgis, can anybody suggest me, how can i do it? or redirect me to where i can get a solution.

**EDIT:**
This is my polygon (`select st_asewkt((select "Fence" from "GeoFence" where "FenceId"=13))`)

`"SRID=900913;POLYGON((78.421783447257 17.420097759577 0,78.528900146476 17.423373494038 0,78.528213500968 17.333597145753 0,78.421783447257 17.332941682216 0,78.422470092765 17.332941682216 0,78.421783447257 17.420097759577 0))"`

Comment: Please do not cross post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27964509/postgis-calculate-distance-between-point-polygon-circle As I already explained on that post, you need to use ST_Distance_Sphere to get distance in meters between lat/lon points and if one of your coordinate pairs is in 900913 then use [ST_Transform](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html) to convert to 4326 first.

Comment: I tried this `select ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_Transform((select "Fence" from "GeoFence" where "FenceId"=13),4326),ST_GeomFromText('POINT(79.268309 17.057432 0.0)',4326))` but it is giving too big value 
8867239.50541838, actually then length should be below 90KM. Anything wrong i did?

Comment: Yes, you need to convert your fence to 4326, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the distance between two sets of lat/lon, 4326, points, then you can use [ST_Distance_Sphere](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Distance_Sphere.html) or for more accuracy, [ST_Distance_Spheroid](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html). If your fence table is in 900913, then use, ST_Transform to convert, so that both sets of points are in a common SRID.

```
SELECT 
  ST_Distance_Sphere(
     (select ST_Transform("Fence", 4326) FROM "GeoFence" WHERE "FenceId"=13)),
      ST_GeomFromText('POINT(79.268309 17.057432 0.0)', 4326))
```

Comment: But that is not expected value at all, 8867239.50541838/1000 = 8867.23950541838 KM, but value should be below 90KM.

Comment: Can you show the coordinates (raw, not transformed) for select "Fence" from "GeoFence" where "FenceId" = 13 please.

Comment: I added that in my question, is that what you are expecting?

Comment: OK, the problem is that those coordinates are already in 4326, not 900913, which is in meters, and typically has values in the millions. This query, SELECT 
  ST_Distance_Sphere(
     st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((78.421783447257 17.420097759577 0,78.528900146476 17.423373494038 0,78.528213500968 17.333597145753 0,78.421783447257 17.332941682216 0,78.422470092765 17.332941682216 0,78.421783447257 17.420097759577 0))',4326),
      ST_GeomFromText('POINT(79.268309 17.057432 0.0)', 4326));
gives  84400.9 meters, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: i am not sure why my `st_asewkt` given that result. But your query giving correct result. Thanks

Comment: It is because you were setting the SRID to 900913 when it was already in 4326.

Comment: `SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere((select "Fence" from "GeoFence" where "FenceId"=13), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(79.268309 17.057432 0.0)', 4326))` giving error -- Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography. Any thing wrong? But this one giving result - `SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(st_geomfromtext(st_astext((select "Fence" from "GeoFence" where "FenceId"=13)),4326), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(79.268309 17.057432 0.0)', 4326))`

Comment: I think you GeoFence table has the wrong srid set. Try running http://postgis.org/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html on it, setting it to 4326.

Comment: after trying above link it is working fine. It is working with `ST_SetSRID` also, but thinking about performance, what is that 900913 & 4326? any doc?